# Deploying ERC20 Contract gives error code -32000: Transaction Underpriced

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, metamask

I'm trying to create an ERC20 token in solidity and upon hitting "Deploy" it prompts me to enter a Gas Price.

I'm entering 0 as I don't have any ETH in my metamask wallet and this is only for a school project.

Upon clicking deploy, I'm prompted with this error:

creation of SSUERC20 errored: Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32000,"message":"transaction underpriced"}}'

Is there any way to make an ERC20 token and deploy it for free?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot deploy anything for free on the Ethereum mainnet. Gas price can never be zero on any network.

However, you can deploy for free if you use [one of the Ethereum testnets](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/networks/#testnets).

On that page you can also find links to "faucets" which will give you Ether on those testnets for free (it will only work there, not on mainnet), which you can use to try deploying whatever you want.